# How can i receive broadcast notification for admin guard?

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-5.7, laravel-echo

I am doing broadcast notification for admin guard and have done broadcast notification on pusher server, notifications are displayed in pusher server but i am not able to print notification on console
This is my app.js code

```
Echo.private('App.Model.Admin.Admin.' + userId)
    .notification((notification) => {
        console.log(notification.type);
});
```

This is my `channel.php` code

```
Broadcast::channel('App.Model.Admin.Admin.{admin}',function ($user, Admin $admin){
    return $user->id === $admin->id; 
});
```

This is my `BroadcastServiceProvider.php` code

```
public function boot()
{
    Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:admin']]);

    /*
     * Authenticate the user's personal channel...
     */
    Broadcast::channel('App.Model.Admin.Admin.*', function ($user, $userId) {
        return $user->id === $userId;
    });
}
```

This is my channel name on pusher server

```
private-App.Model.Admin.Admin.1
```